# when I enter inputs to be 1st station is the nearest it print min value as 0 not 1 why this happen? all other things are working correctly

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float val[4][2], a[3];


    int j, i, min, y; 
     float cordianation_entry ()
{
       printf ("enter your cordianation-");
  
       scanf("%f,%f", &val[0][0], &val[0][1]);
  
       for (j = 1; j < 4; j++)
    {  
           printf ("enter station %d coordination-", j);
      
           scanf ("%f,%f", &val[j][0], &val[j][1]);  
}
}
     float results_analysis ()
{
  
 
        for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
      
         a[i] =(pow ((val[i][0] - val[0][0]), 2)) + (pow ((val[i][1] - val[0][1]), 2));
      
         a[i] = sqrt (a[i]);
      
         y= a[2];
      
         printf ("%d\n", i);
      
         printf ("\n*distance to station %d is %f\n", i, a[i]);
      
      if (a[i] < 100)
    
      printf ("\tDistance is Low");
      
      else if (a[i] < 1000 && a[i] >= 100)
    
      printf ("\tDistance is Moderate");
      
      else
    
      printf ("\tDistance is High");  
      if (a[i] < y)
      min = i;  
}
      printf("\nStation %d is the nearest station", min);           
}

// in this statemnt if i =1 it print as 0 , If first station becomes nearest upper statemnt print station 0 in the nearest

void main ()
{
       cordianation_entry ();
  
        results_analysis ();
}
```

Comment: Indentation, please, and make it consistent. That will make the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: You probably also need some more time with a decent beginners book or two, and perhaps even some classes. That's to learn good habits like not using global variables and how to use function arguments. As well as something you really need to learn if you want to program: ***Debugging***.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it (like showing your actual and full input, copy-pasted as text).

Comment: Lastly a major problem, leading to *undefined behavior*: You define `a` to have three elements, which means its indexes are `0`, `1` and `2`. Now what indexes are you actually using for `a`? Think more about the loop `for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)` in the `results_analysis` function.